# Get data from ajax every 2 seconds and display it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

### Plot

I save every visit to a count.dat file on my website. It just outputs `123450`. So it displays pageviews till the second of website.

### Problem

Firstly I was displaying it using `file_get_contents` but then I tried to display it every two seconds using ajax. But the resulting div is empty, always.

### What I have tried so far is..

JS:

```
    (function(d, s, id) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tth').load('count.dat', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 2000);
        });
    }
```

count.dat

```
123456
```

HTML

```
<div id="tth"></div>
```

### Additional info :

Jquery version

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your Javascript is missing a `});`.

Comment: I think this is similar http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/ajax-auto-refresh-volume-ii

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen still :(

Comment: can you try removing line   (function(d, s, id) { and let everything remian

Comment: What is the full URL for `count.dat`? Do you get any errors in your console? Do you use any caching?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen the problem is solved now BTW thanks for your will to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tth').load('count.dat', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 2000);
        });
    }
```

try

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tth').load('count.dat', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 2000);
        });
    }
```

Comment: still can't get it work , div is empty the link is [here..](http://www.lyricsnext.com) div is before hits.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(refreshTable, 2000);
});

function refreshTable(){
    $('#tth').load('count.dat');
}
```

Comment: Your code worked but it's not refreshing, I use cloudflare, could this be a caching problem.

Comment: I use this code on my site to refresh header of a box every 30 seconds. No idea why isn't working for you :(

Comment: Using `setInterval()` is not a good idea when continuously polling a URL. If the request takes longer than 2 seconds to complete then you will end up with overlapping requests. Using `setTimeout()`, immediately after the request is done, is a better idea.

Comment: Never used it for lower interval than 30 seconds, and always used ajax instead of load (needed more complex data handling). And I don't know much about `setTimeout()` either